# Laravel Godday apache hosting is saying You don't have permission to access /laravel/ on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, http-status-code-403

I am using hosting and want to run a Laravel 5.1 Project on this hosting but when ever i open the laravel folder using 
My PHP Version is 5.5

```
http://pndhub.com/laravelss/
```

then it shows me this

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /laravel/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

But the same code works on the my other hosting account server 
here is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If i click on error on cpanel then it shows me this errors

```
[autoindex:error] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/myhosting/public_html/laravel/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,index.shtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html,welcome.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Answer (score 1):

The directory of virtual host must be

```
/home/myhosting/public_html/laravel/public
```

Comment: Thanks for replying can you please tell me where i can find virtual host in my cpanel

Comment: i think that is not available at cpanel. You must have ssh access or access to whm. https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/change-document-root.84317/. I think you must Contact support center      http://pndhub.com/laravelss/public/ is working correctly

Comment: what is ssh access how can i get that it is a shared hosting i can not get whm access